# Есть ли какой-нибудь способ сократить код?

Tags: python, оптимизация

Пусть вновь имеются N станций и таблица цен на проезд между ними. Требуется выяснить, как дешевле проехать от одной определённой станции до другой: напрямую или с одной пересадкой на третьей станции, и если дешевле с пересадкой, то где дешевле всего. Маршруты, требующие более одной пересадки, мы не рассматриваем.

**Формат ввода**

На первой строке вводится натуральное число N — количество станций.
Далее следует N − 1 строка, составляющая половину таблицы цен.
После этого следуют номера станций A и B — желаемые пункты отправления и прибытия (на одной строке, через пробел.).

**Формат вывода**

Выводится одно число — номер станции, пересадкой через которую дешевле всего проехать из A в B. Если таких несколько, выводится наименьший номер. Если дешевле всего не делать пересадок, а ехать напрямую, выводится A (в том числе в том случае, когда существуют маршруты с пересадками за ту же цену).

**Пример**

**Ввод**

```
3
10
1 2
0 1
```

**Вывод**

```
2
```

есть ли способ сократить код, чтобы выглядел поэлегантнее и  краще , чем сейчас?

```
n = int(input())
s = [[]]
 
for i in range(n - 1):
    s.append([int(j) for j in input().split()])
 
station = input().split()
a, a1 = int(station[0]), int(station[1])
 
l = s[max(a, a1)][min(a, a1)]
b = -1
 
for i in range(n):
    if i != a and i != a1:
        if (l > s[max(a, i)][min(a, i)] + s[max(i, a1)][min(i, a1)]):
            l = s[max(i, a1)][min(i, a1)] + s[max(i, a1)][min(i, a1)]
            b = i
 
if b != -1:
    print(b)
else:
    print(a)
```

**UPDATE**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
5
10
1 1
1 1 1
100 1 1 1
4 0
```

**Ожидаемый результат**

```
2
```

**Вывод**

```
3
```

Comment: а есть еще тесткейсы к этой задаче? или ссылка на источник?

Comment: @Jack_oS да, есть , но в виде таблицы, сейчас добавлю в вопрос
, нет, к сожалению доступ к источнику только по специальному логину и паролю

Comment: А оптимизация и сокращение кода - не разные вещи ?)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME ну по логике в оптимизации написано _Оптимизация — улучшение дизайна или реализации_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

чуть-чуть поджал ваш код:

```
n = int(input())
s = [[]] + [list(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(n - 1)]

a, a1 = map(int, input().split())

l = s[max(a, a1)][min(a, a1)]
b = -1

for i in range(n):
    if i != a and i != a1:
        if (l > s[max(i, a)][min(i, a)] + s[max(i, a1)][min(i, a1)]):
            l = s[max(i, a1)][min(i, a1)] + s[max(i, a1)][min(i, a1)]
            b = i

print((a, b)[b != -1])
```

и сразу вопрос - а у вас случаем вот тут не ошибка:

```
        if (l > s[max(i, a)][min(i, a)] + s[max(i, a1)][min(i, a1)]):
            l = s[max(i, a1)][min(i, a1)] + s[max(i, a1)][min(i, a1)]
```

и надо

```
        if (l > s[max(i, a)][min(i, a)] + s[max(i, a1)][min(i, a1)]):
            l = s[max(i, a)][min(i, a)] + s[max(i, a1)][min(i, a1)]
```

?

если так, то тогда можно еще чуть поджать:

```
n = int(input())
s = [[]] + [list(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(n - 1)]

a, a1 = map(int, input().split())

l = s[max(a, a1)][min(a, a1)]
b = -1

for i in range(n):
    if i != a and i != a1:
        l_new = s[max(i, a)][min(i, a)] + s[max(i, a1)][min(i, a1)]
        l, b = (l_new, i) if (l > l_new) else (l, b)

print((a, b)[b != -1])
```

Answer (score 2):

Определяем функцию вычисления стоимости, которая кроме прочего считает стоимость проезда от станции до самой себя равной нулю. Это полезное обобщение, которое позволит рассматривать поездку без пересадки `a -> b` как частный случай поездки с пересадкой `a -> a -> b` или `a -> b -> b`.

Находим первую из оптимальных промежуточных станций, отдавая предпочтение станции `a`

```
def cost(i, j):
    return 0 if i == j else table[max(i, j) - 1][min(i, j)]

n = int(input())
table = [[int(x) for x in input().split()] for _ in range(n - 1)]
a, b = map(int, input().split())

print(min(a, *range(n), key=lambda x: cost(a, x) + cost(x, b)))
```